# Using NULLIF() in WHERE clause changes planner

Tags: postgresql

In 9.6.3 adding NULLIF() in the WHERE clause changes the plan from a bitmap heap scan to an index scan and changes execution time from about 0.3ms to 43,000ms.

Here is a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21062148/how-to-query-postgres-on-optional-params

This is the fast query and plan:

```
SELECT
        c.name_first, c.name_last, c.postal_code,
        v.tag as plate_number, v.tag_state as plate_state, v.year, v.make, v.model
FROM customers_vehicles AS v
        JOIN customers AS c ON (v.customer_id = c.id)
WHERE ('XXXXXX'::text is null OR v.tag='XXXXXX');
┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                                  QUERY PLAN                                                                   │
├───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Nested Loop  (cost=824.67..451863.32 rows=43830 width=228) (actual time=0.202..0.203 rows=1 loops=1)                                          │
│   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on customers_vehicles v  (cost=824.12..121946.77 rows=43830 width=164) (actual time=0.104..0.104 rows=1 loops=1)       │
│         Recheck Cond: (tag = 'XXXXXX'::text)                                                                                                  │
│         Heap Blocks: exact=1                                                                                                                  │
│         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on customers_vehicles_tag_idx  (cost=0.00..813.16 rows=43830 width=0) (actual time=0.090..0.090 rows=1 loops=1) │
│               Index Cond: (tag = 'XXXXXX'::text)                                                                                              │
│   ->  Index Scan using customers_pkey on customers c  (cost=0.56..7.52 rows=1 width=128) (actual time=0.093..0.094 rows=1 loops=1)            │
│         Index Cond: (id = v.customer_id)                                                                                                      │
│ Planning time: 0.268 ms                                                                                                                       │
│ Execution time: 0.256 ms                                                                                                                      │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

And this is the slow query and plan:

```
SELECT
        c.name_first, c.name_last, c.postal_code,
        v.tag as plate_number, v.tag_state AS plate_state, v.year, v.make, v.model
FROM customers_vehicles AS v
        JOIN customers as c on (v.customer_id = c.id)
WHERE (nullif('XXXXXX'::text,'') IS NULL OR v.tag='XXXXXX');
┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                                                    QUERY PLAN                                                                                    │
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Nested Loop  (cost=1.12..7509681.67 rows=87441 width=228) (actual time=5462.111..42209.513 rows=1 loops=1)                                                                       │
│   ->  Index Scan using customers_vehicles_customer_id_idx on customers_vehicles v  (cost=0.56..6921180.68 rows=87441 width=164) (actual time=5462.023..42209.423 rows=1 loops=1) │
│         Filter: ((NULLIF('XXXXXX'::text, ''::text) IS NULL) OR (tag = 'XXXXXX'::text))                                                                                             │
│         Rows Removed by Filter: 8766005                                                                                                                                          │
│   ->  Index Scan using customers_pkey on customers c  (cost=0.56..6.72 rows=1 width=128) (actual time=0.080..0.081 rows=1 loops=1)                                               │
│         Index Cond: (id = v.customer_id)                                                                                                                                         │
│ Planning time: 0.209 ms                                                                                                                                                          │
│ Execution time: 42209.549 ms                                                                                                                                                     │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

The only difference is in the slow query in the WHERE clause: `'XXXXXX' IS NULL` changes to `nullif('XXXXXX','') IS NULL`. It seems the planner cannot optimize out the first condition if it contains `NULLIF()`. Is there a way to coerce it into doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your predicate to the following:

`WHERE ('XXXXXX'::text is null OR v.tag='XXXXXX' OR 'XXXXXX' = '');`

As this is effectively what the `NULLIF` statement is doing from a logic standpoint.  I'm assuming `'XXXXXX'` is a column in this scenario and not just a random string of `X`'s, correct?

Comment: `'XXXXXX'` would be an input parameter, it could be replaced with `$1`.

Comment: @IanTimothy This should do it for you even if an empty string is passed in as a parameter.

Comment: Man so easy. Just need another brain on it sometimes.